# Visual Studio 2008 Development Server not starting

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2008, localhost, webdev.webserver

I have a C# web service that I am trying to debug in Visual Studio 2008, and when I try to run it, Internet Explorer pops-up as expected, but it just displays 'waiting for response from localhost...' in the status bar. I have left it running for a few minutes and it never responds.

I have other web services that I am able to debug fine, is VS2005 and 2008. The problem web service is impersonating a different identity in the web.config file, but I have no problems with this same user on a different web service (in VS2005).

Does anybody have any ideas on what might be preventing it from starting up? Interestingly, a colleague has the same problem with a web service that IS working on my machine, even though we are working with identical code. Something must be configured differently...

By the way, I've noticed that the 'Temporary ASP.NET Files' folder is missing from both
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework and C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64... I certainly haven't deleted them, and other web services debug okay, so is this just a red herring?

We are also on a domain which has its own firewall (outside of the developers' control) - could this be blocking it?

EDIT: I have just removed the user impersonation for a quick test, and it worked. So there must be something about Visual Studio 2008 that does not want to run when impersonating THIS particular user. Any ideas what configuration I would need to change to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same issues with impersonation; I don't know if Cassini (the built-in VS web server) supports this properly. About the best advice I can give is to either use Local IIS with an app pool running as your impersonated user or to attach your debugger using remote debugging to a remote IIS server.

I believe using Local IIS will attach correctly & automatically if configured as much in the Web tab of Project Properties. You'll have to run VS as an admin to get the virtual directories setup automatically by VS in IIS.

Comment: You gave me an idea - I tried running VS as administrator before trying the local IIS thing, and it ran fine when impersonating the user... I'll mark yours as the answer in a round-a-bout way! ;o)   The change is now preventing VSLauncher from directly launching VS2008 solutions, but I can live with that for the time being.